# multi sql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, wampserver

i have a table of this sort:

```
| name    |  salary |  day  |  month   |
| james   |  200.00 |    2  | january  |
| marie   |  400.00 |    4  | january  |
| jimmy   |  300.00 |    7  | january  |
| Fredd   |  700.00 |    3  | february |
| rosieli |  500.00 |    5  | february |
| rosela  |  800.00 |    6  | february |
```

if the table name is 'db_table', how do I write an sql select query to select records from 4th January to 5th February. 
something like:

```
select * from db_table between day='4',month='january' and day='5' and month='february'";
```

please how do I write a proper sql statement to get the desired results.so that the table looks like this:

```
| name    |  salary |  day  |  month   | 
| marie   |  400.00 |    4  | january  |
| jimmy   |  300.00 |    7  | january  |
| Fredd   |  700.00 |    3  | february |
| rosieli |  500.00 |    5  | february |
```

thank you

Comment: am using MYSQL in wampserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should do this using dates.

```
select t.*
from t
where str_to_date(concat_ws(2020, month, day), '%Y %M %d') between '2020-01-04' and '2020-02-05';
```

When possible, date comparisons should be made using dates.

I used `2020` because it is a leap year, so it will handle February 29th.

Once you've solved this, you should fix your data model to contain an actual date rather than a month/day combination.

Comment: ok thank you. and instead of 'yyyy-mm-dd' module, will the query be able to work on this date format too 'dd / mm / yyyy' @Gordon

Comment: @RodneyNart . . . I strongly recommend using ISO/SQL standard date formats for dates.  If you want to use another format, I would suggest using `str_to_date()`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make the day a number but this is it:

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE (day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'February')
```

For e.g. January to April:

```
SELECT *
FROM db_table
WHERE (day >= 4 and month = 'January')
   OR (day <= 5 and month = 'April')
   OR month IN ('February','March')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a comparable string out of `month` and `day` to use in a `between` statement:

```
select * from db_table where 
concat(case month 
         when 'january' then '01'
         when 'february' then '02'
         ........................
         when 'december' then '12'
       end, case when day < 10 then '0' else '' end, day) between '0104' and '0205'
```

Like this you can compare any date range by modifying only the starting and ending dates.

Comment: How would this return Jan 6th?

Comment: You need a range from 4 january to 5 february?

Comment: This will randomly combine day and month

Comment: yes @forpas. a range of records from 4 January to 5 february

Answer (score 0):

> how do I write an sql select query to select records from 4th January to 5th February.

```
select  *
from    db_table
where   (month = 'january' and 4 <= cast(day as int)) or
        (month = 'february' and cast(day as int) <= 5)
```

Note that a table design with separate month and day columns makes querying hard.  It would get even harder at year boundaries.  A better design would make use of your database's native datetime column type.  Then you can query like:

```
select  *
from    db_table
where   dt_col between '2019-01-04' and '2019-02-05'
```

Comment: thank you very much for the advice. and the code too.